# Can I accept unicoins for micro-payments in my game?

Tags: free-to-play, payment

I'm developing a free-to-play game on Android and iOS and Facebook. I see that Unicoins can be purchased in many ways, a lot more that I'll ever be able to implement myself (Paypal, Bitcoins, Gold, Reddit karma! I mean: wow!).

Is there a way I can accept them as micro-payments and then turn them back into real money?

Comment: I think this is kinda getting out of scope since we're now discussing cryptocurrency rather than game development...
But isn't the concept of unicoin to destroy other cryptocurrencies in order to generate unicoins?
(generate a bitcoin, destroy it, get unicoins).
That makes them kinda hard to come by.
Besides this, until a someone considers unicoins worth anything, investing in unicoin will be like chasing a unicorn...

Comment: wait a minute... *looks at banner on StackExchange*

Comment: oh *THOSE* unicoins.

Comment: Hold off for the moment: the payment methods seem to be broken, meaning the only way to acquire them is via mining. The labour is being outsourced to sweatshops, making Unicoins an ethically questionable currency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes

[image]

However, there are some restrictions. As stated in the terms:

> Not legal tender **except in localities with citizenship rights for unicorns**

And, a little known fact is that [Scotland's national animal](http://www.scotsman.com/lifestyle/heritage/scottish-fact-of-the-week-scotland-s-official-animal-the-unicorn-1-2564399), is the **Unicorn**. Also, I'm pretty sure Internetland allows them, 'cause they, like, for sure allow Unicorns.

[image]

The majesty of these animals is unparalleled, so I'm not sure why they're not allowed citizenship rights everywhere, but there you have it.

tl;dr

As long as you're operating in Scotland or Internetland you can accept Unicoins.

[image]

I apologize, but for technical reasons I cannot currently accept payments with Unicoins for this answer.

Comment: Unicorn haters be downvoting.

Comment: +1 for the magic of unicorns.. @Byte56 Now I have higher rep than you :D Except that I am the only who can see it :( .... but I want to believe that :D

Comment: As long as I don't look at your rep, it ***will*** be higher than mine. You just keep believing!

Comment: Great! I guess I should contact a Scottish bank to see how to convert those to proper $$$.

Comment: @LaurentCouvidou please send me the details :D